# Angular2 Form How to Get Specific Error Type?

Tags: forms, angular

I 'm trying to hide/show the appropriate error message if the given field is empty,too short, or too long.  Here is a portion of my form:

```
<form  #applicationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveApplication()" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="row-fluid">
             <div [class.has-error]="name.touched && name.errors" class="form-group">
                   <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label form-lbl">Name</label>
                       <div class="col-sm-10">
                           <input type="text"
                                   class="form-control" placeholder="Name" 
                                    minlength="8" maxlength="200" required 
                                   [(ngModel)]="application.Name" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm">
    <p *ngIf="name.errors.minlength" class="help-block">Name is too short, it must be at least 8 characters.</p>
    <p *ngIf="name.errors.maxlength" class="help-block">Name is too long, it must be less than 200 characters.</p>
    <p *ngIf="name.errors.required" class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
                         </div>
                </div>
       </div>...
```

If i comment out the *ngIf's in the paragraph tags the form works otherwise i get a js error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'minlength' of null"

Which makes me think that the errors collection is null, how do i get at the specific error?

For reference I'm using this:  [Deborah Kurata - ng-conf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0)

The solution recommended by @peppermcknight works.  Adding the following check in the ngIf resolved the issue:

```
 <p *ngIf="applicationForm.dirty && name.errors.minlength" class="help-block">Name is too short, it must be at least 8 characters.</p>
 <p *ngIf="applicationForm.dirty && name.errors.maxlength" class="help-block">Name is too long, it must be less than 200 characters.</p>
 <p *ngIf="applicationForm.dirty && name.errors.required" class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This error might be occurring when the component is first loaded. Try to make a reference to the form in your HTML and then checking if the form is dirty inside your ngIf.
    `*ngIf="!form.dirty && name.errors.minlength`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the safe-navigation (Elvis) operator

```
<p *ngIf="applicationForm.dirty && name.errors?.minlength" class="he
```

When no error is reported `name.errors` is `null` and therefore `name.errors.minlength` throws.

Answer (score 0):

This works on RC4 using the new forms 'module'.

```
<form #tagsForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <input name="myInput" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}">
    <div [hidden]="!tagsForm.form.controls?.myInput?.errors?.pattern">Invalid pattern</div>
</form>
```

I was forced to use this because, although the approach documented at ..

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

works, my unit tests failed with ..

There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

For more on this error see ...

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9363

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
<div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="help-block">
    Name is required.
</div>
```

`.pristine`: Control's value has changed
`.valid`: Control's value is valid

Example from the docs: [angular.io forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Comment: no context to this answer -1